# Writing a simple rc.d script in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, csh, rc.d

I would like to run the ELK stack in a FreeBSD Jail on an FreeNAS host. I have a hard time to get an simple init/rc.d script to work.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/rc.subr

name=logstash
rcvar=logstash_enable

load_rc_config $name

logstash_bin="/usr/local/bin/${name}/bin/${name}"
logstash_conf="/usr/local/etc/${name}/${name}.conf"
logstash_pid="/var/run/${name}.pid"

command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
command_args="-f -p ${logstash_pid} ${logstash_bin} -f ${logstash_conf} web"

run_rc_command "$1"
```

I can execute the script and it will return that logstash now started but "ps" tells me another story.

```
root@logstash:/var/log # service logstash start
Starting logstash.
root@logstash:/var/log # ps aux
USER   PID %CPU %MEM   VSZ  RSS TT  STAT STARTED    TIME COMMAND
root  2963  0.0  0.0 12076 1636 ??  SsJ   3:58PM 0:00.02 /usr/sbin/syslogd -s
root  3014  0.0  0.0 14176 1592 ??  SsJ   3:58PM 0:00.01 /usr/sbin/cron -s
root 57344  0.0  0.0 17564 3736  0  SJ    5:31PM 0:00.18 csh
root 61945  0.0  0.0 14220 1768  0  R+J   7:24PM 0:00.00 ps aux
root@logstash:/var/log #
```

If I print the content of `$command` and `$command_args` out and enter it manually it works perfectly.

output from "command="echo /usr/sbin/daemon":

```
/etc/rc.d/logstash: WARNING: cannot read shebang line from echo
/etc/rc.d/logstash: WARNING: run_rc_command: cannot run echo /usr/sbin/daemon
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please try `command="echo /usr/sbin/daemon"`. Does it print the full command?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the logstash_bin is right?  "/usr/local/bin/logstash/bin/logstash" looks suspicious.

There is also an RC debugging mechanism (eg "rc_debug=true /usr/local/etc/rc.d/logstash start"), but I'm not sure if it will help you in this case.